What is allowing septic plant smell through shower drain?
In our very old stone farmhouse, there is a wetroom downstairs with a shower drain.  Ever since having the septic tank emptied, and then replaced with a treatment plant, a foul stench comes from the shower drain.
There is no smell from the toilet and sink in the same wetroom.
There is an obvious escape pipe up the front of the house which serves the kitchen sink and upstairs bathroom, none of which smell.
I can't see any obvious escape pipe for the wetroom in the back.  But it's strange that the sink and toilet don't smell, only the shower.  All the pipes go out the front to the septic drain, so I guess the wetroom is connected at a distance to the front escape pipe.
Is it possible to deduce anything from the picture of the shower drain or general knowledge about a possible cause for this (including the escape pipe answer)?  It would be great to get rid of this smell without having to replumb the entire room, but I can accept that too if I have to!


Is there a crawlspace or basement underneath that room which would allow you to look at the drain plumbing?

Unfortunately not.  It's a stone farmhouse built on stone next to a quarry.  I'm thinking maybe the original plumber didn't want to/couldn't dig down far enough, wishing he had though.

As other answers have indicated, this drain likely does not have a P trap. There are several low-profile and tight quarters options for P traps, and depending on your location and code requirements, you could have several options.

Bottle trap - more common in Europe than North America, shower drain bottle traps can be very low profile and only slightly larger in diameter than the shower drain. This might not require excavation.

low profile P trap - there are different types, some with very tight turns or flat tubing instead of round.

in line trap - these are often banned by local regulation or building code, but if the plumbing is laid in solid stone and you don't have a local regulation, then placing an in line trap somewhere after the shower drain in the waste line but before it joins to a soil line or the main sewer line will stop sewer gas from venting into your shower.


The different traps may work better or worse for your situation, depending on how or if your plumbing lines are vented, their size, and their slope.

Amazing!  I didn't realize there was one that goes in the drain itself.  That could save us a lot of heartache and money!

Sink and toilet have something called p-trap, which prevents smells, your shower does not seem to have one.

Or you have get the trap run dry. Or there is a vent stack problem and the trap is not quite sufficient to block the higher-than-expected gas pressure, in which case the fix is to make sure the vent is clear

Thanks both.  I'm trying boiling water and bleach first every day and seeing if that helps.  Eventually we'll redo the bathroom and then we can make sure there is a p-trap in there.  I think it's not there at all because you can actually hear the treatment plant running through the pipe.
